# Print with comma and 2 decimal places with padding

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have a money value that I need to print with padding. I want it printed with commas and 2 decimal places. I know how to print it with padding and with commas and 2 decimal places. How do I do both though?'

For padding I'm using `"{:>11.2f}".format(value)`

For commas with decimal places I'm using `"{0:,.2f}".format(value)`

Answer (score 4):

You can combine right alignment, comma separation and fixed point notation as follows. See [Format Specification Mini Language](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for more details.

```
"{:>11,.2f}".format(value)
```